Computer not booting after installing Ubuntu next to Windows
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside an existing Windows 10 installation on a HP ProBook 470 G2 and let the Ubuntu installer take care of shrinking the Windows partition and rewriting the partition table. The Ubuntu installation ran through without errors, but on reboot afterwards, the computer got stuck with the error
BootDevice Not Found
Please install an operating sytem on your hard disk. 
Hard Disk - (3F0)

Running gparted on a live system shows the following partition structure:

The contents of /dev/sda1 (mountpoint /media/ubuntu/System-reserviert) looks like this

The contents of /dev/sda5 looks like this

So it seems /dev/sda1 is the UEFI partition and the grub boot manager is located on /dev/sda5. As a first attempt to fix it, I copied /dev/sda5/EFI to /dev/sda1/EFI, but that didn't fix anything, the computer still gets stuck with the same error when I try to boot from the hard disk.
Any ideas how I could get this to work as a dual boot (managed by grub)?


and rewriting the GUID partition table

You don't have one; you only have a BIOS-style MBR partition table. (It's the only kind that has an 'extended' partition with more partitions inside – with GPT it would be a flat list.)

So it seems /dev/sda1 is the UEFI partition

No, /dev/sda1 is Microsoft's BIOS sort-of-equivalent of an EFI system partition. It contains similar-looking files but is used exclusively for "legacy" BIOS boot mode.
The only EFI partition here is /dev/sda5, which Ubuntu has just created.

In other words, you ended up with mixed mode OS installations – Windows has been set up to boot in legacy mode, but Ubuntu's set up to boot in EFI mode. This could be made to work, but:
Due to it being a MBR-partitioned disk that only had one partition slot empty, the Ubuntu installer has placed the EFI system partition inside an extended partition (the MBR workaround to bypass its 4-partition limit). The support for parsing extended and logical partitions is not part of the EFI specification, so it's very likely that the laptop's firmware will not find GRUB in there.
Copying files into /dev/sda1 is not enough; for one, it's an NTFS partition and I don't think HP's firmware supports that (the UEFI specification only requires FAT, everything else is up to the manufacturer).
Second, EFI bootloaders normally have their exact path (including the partition ID) stored in the firmware's NVRAM – if the firmware has been told to look for grubx64.efi in partition X, it will not look for grubx64.efi in partition Y.
(It will look for a single specific path, EFI/boot/bootx64.efi, which may be a copy of Windows Bootmgr or a copy of GRUB if you want, but I don't think the Ubuntu installer sets that up.)


Any ideas how I could get this to work as a dual boot (managed by grub)?

Start by deleting the two Ubuntu partitions (and the now-empty extended partition); it'll be easier to reinstall than to move them.
There are a few ways to make this work, but with Windows already using three of the four MBR partition slots (boot+OS+recovery), I think it would be easiest to convert that to a GPT+UEFI installation first. So boot from a Windows installation USB disk (making sure to select the "UEFI: USB" entry from the boot menu), hit Shift-F10 at the welcome screen, and use the mbr2gpt tool to perform the conversion.
(Converting to GPT while remaining in legacy-BIOS-boot mode could be possible in theory, but I've only ever heard that Windows does not like that combination, and your PC is modern enough that it should be working perfectly fine in UEFI mode.)
Once you have Windows booting in EFI mode from the GPT disk, install Ubuntu anew (again making sure you boot the USB stick in UEFI mode).

Many thanks for your explanations, I've corrected the question title.
I got the notebook 2nd hand and don't have a Windows installation medium- is it needed for the mbr2gpt conversion only or would reinstalling Windows be unavoidable?
"Start by deleting the two Ubuntu partitions (and the now-empty extended partition)"  basically means deleting sda4, sda5 and sda6, correct?

Yes, all three of them. You can download a Windows 10 or Win11 ISO for free from Microsoft, then extract it to a USB stick using something like Rufus – or use the MS "Media Creation Tool" to do it in one stage. Parts of the conversion could be done from Linux (using gdisk and mkfs.fat) but the final step of actually installing the Windows bootloader will still require Windows. If you don't have a spare USB stick nor a DVD, you can try using the same mbr2gpt from within the running Windows installation; often it works, but it's not guaranteed.

Thanks a lot. Before booting from the Windows USB stick and running mbr2gpt, I probably have to switch the BIOS to UEFI mode?

Most of them already offer boot entries for both modes in the F8 (F12, etc) boot menu – and the laptop is new enough that it'll probably always offer UEFI (i.e. the settings probably let you choose betwee "both UEFI and BIOS" and "UEFI-only"). Given that Ubuntu's installer decided to create an EFI system partition, you probably booted it in UEFI mode earlier anyway.

@grawity_u1686 Actually, one of the beauties of EFI requiring FAT support is that is can just read the bootloader as a file off the media. No need to install it to a special sector like in legacy mode. Windows or Linux should be bootable on external media as long as the \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI file for that OS was copied over. I have had issues in the past, but it's generally something like my USB Stick was actually ExFAT which isn't supported or had multiple partitions confusing EFI.
